# UTF-8 in nodejs with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, character-encoding, socket.io

I'm having trouble passing utf-8 encoded strings to the client using nodejs and socket.io. It does not seem to matter what transport (websocket, flashsocket or xhr-polling) I'm using.

The code is very plain and simple:

Server:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
, io = require('socket.io').listen(app,{log:false});

app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html','utf-8',
        function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            res.writeHead(500);
            return res.end('Error loading index.html');
          }
          var type="text/html";
          res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':type + "; charset=utf-8"});
          res.end(data,'utf8');
        });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('msg', { text: 'æøå' });//Here we send the utf-8 characters to the client
});
```

Client:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.0.12/socket.io/socket.io.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  window.WEB_SOCKET_SWF_LOCATION = 'http://192.168.0.12/socket.io/static/flashsocket/WebSocketMain.swf';
  var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.0.12');
  socket.on('msg', function(data){alert(data.text);}); //here the data is recieved and put into the alert box
  ...
  ...
```

It seems like the data is always UTF-8 double encoded like this:
[image: Client alert with data from nodejs server]

I'm using nodejs 0.8.17 and socket.io 0.9

Comment: In what encoding format is your .js file saved?

Comment: It's all utf-8, and the index file displays fine on the client if I add utf-8 encoded characters (e.g. æøå) directly in it. Seems like something is happening in the transmission using socket.io.

Comment: Please try this instead `socket.emit('msg', { text: 'æøå'.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) });`, what is alerted?

Comment: What is this? -It outputs "fffd"

Comment: @jornare thanks, the problem is obvious now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your node.js file (the first snippet of code) is not saved in UTF-8 encoding, node.js expects files to be saved in UTF-8. This depends on your text editor but usually when you save a file, you should be able to choose an encoding.

Comment: I thought I had checked that twice, but obviously Zend Studio played a trick on me :/ Thanx!!